# Why should javax.servlet.GenericServlet implement javax.servlet.ServletConfig?

Tags: inheritance, servlets, jakarta-ee

I was having a look through the servlet-api.jar source code and found out (to my utter bewilderment) that javax.servlet.GenericServlet implements javax.servlet.ServletConfig.

Now, I don't boast to be an OOP scholar, but I do remember reading that although OOP provides the concept of inheritance, inheritance as a feature should be applied only when the child has an IS-A relationship with the parent.

"GenericServlet IS-A ServletConfig" does not sound right to me. Is any one aware of why was such a design decision taken ? (Apart from exposing ServletConfig's methods and attributes to GenericServlet) ?

Answer (score 1):

Because [`ServletConfig`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) is a poorly named interface. I would maybe rather call it `ConfigServlet` or `ServletConfigurator`.

Comment: I like your first suggestion: `ConfigServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

implements and extends are different. implements means that GenericServlet must implement the interface defined in ServletConfig.

ie. a GenericServlet will have the ServletConfig interface, so GenericServlet will be configurable by anything that uses the ServletConfig interface to configure Servlets.

Comment: What I would have expected was that GenericServlet be provided with an instance of ServletConfig, which means that "GenericServlet HAS-A ServletConfig". That sounds better for me.